# Angular 7 and RxJS observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

i'm currently trying to get the hang of RxJs functions. To begin with, i would like to combine two observables with the "concat" function. Without success, unfortunately. Here is my code :

**The component =>**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { interval, range, concat } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-appareils',
  templateUrl: './appareils.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./appareils.component.scss']
})
export class AppareilsComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(private appareilsService : AppareilsService ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    var counter = interval(1000)
    var sequence = range(1, 10)
    var concat(counter,sequence)

    concat.subscribe(
      (value) => {
        this.rxjsValue = value
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log('Uh-oh, an error occurred! : ' + error);
      },
      () => {
        console.log('Observable complete!');
      }
    )
  }

}
```

**The template =>**

```
<p>
{{ rxjsValue }} 
</p>
```

So the idea is that every second, the rxJsValue is edited in the template and rendered to view. Since I'm strictly following the documentation, I'm pretty confused, I have to admit : http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-concat

I can't see the flaw in the logic, could someone point me where the problem is?

Comment: Instead of `var concat(counter,sequence)`, maybe `const concat = concat(counter, sequence)` which returns an observable which you can subscribe to

Comment: Is your intention to display a counter that starts at `1` and ends at `10`, updating every second? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lm2aaz

Comment: Thanks for your answers you guys. Linhh, i've tried your solution and it greets me with an undefined error. Kinda weird, looks like the function is simply not recognized. Alexander, yes this is exactly my point !

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the following by using `interval` as well as operators `take`, and `map` in combination with the `async` pipe:

Component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, interval } from 'rxjs';
import { map, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  rxjsValue$: Observable<number>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.rxjsValue$ = interval(1000).pipe(take(10), map(r => r + 1));
  }
}
```

Template:

```
{{rxjsValue$ | async}}
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lm2aaz) in action.

In your example yor question, you have two separate lines of `import` statements, both from `rxjs`, this can cause compile errors. At minimum, they need to be merged together into a single statement:

```
import { Observable, interval, range, concat } from 'rxjs';
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Elegant solution as well and very helpful ! thanks a lot for your contribution

Comment: You may consider also looking at the [Smart Counter](https://www.learnrxjs.io/recipes/smartcounter.html) example from the learn-rxjs documentation for a more advanced approach.

Comment: I'll be checking this ! much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why you are using concat, you can see here a working example that I have done to you https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-abxeqw

Comment: Thanks a lot for your example, very explicit. Actually, in my case, the concat function doesn't fulfill a purpose in itself, there is no logic behind it. It's nothing more than an exercise to explore RXJS's features. Edit : thanks again for your video, i'll be checking it right now !

Comment: If you are learning, the video that I told you could help you a lot, a good page to learn rxjs (in my opinion better than the official documentation) https://www.learnrxjs.io/ @FitzChevalerie

Comment: once again, thank you very much ! it's always good to have some extra documentation